# Phusion-passenger crash

Tags: apache, passenger

I'm using passenger with apache to run my ruby application. I've noticed that passenger crashes from time to time (apache is still working), and I need to manually restart apache to make it work again.

A look at the log makes me think it occurs when apache changes the log file (archives the current an create a new one). This is what a `tail -F` on tha apache errors log file looks like:

```
tail: ‘/var/log/apache2/error.log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory                                           
tail: ‘/var/log/apache2/error.log’ has appeared;  following end of new file                                                     
[ 2013-10-06 05:05:27.2678 10498/7f3f0cf82740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:459 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_instances_per_app' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.14', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_pid' => '18659', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '1000', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '1001' }                                                                
[Sun Oct 06 05:05:27 2013] [error] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Tried to reuse existing server instance directory /tmp/passenger.1.0.18659, but it has wrong permissions                                                                             
[Sun Oct 06 05:05:27 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

- The message mentions a file in `/tmp` with wrong permissisons, why are they wrong? what should they be? how to make them right?
- The last message "*resuming normal operations*" seems wrong too since passenger is down. Is it a bug? What does it mean?
- What should I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: This *might* be a bug, but needs more investigation. I've filed the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=961

Comment: Nope sorry, I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you start Apache normally, and then tell me how the output of `ls -l -d /tmp/passenger.*` looks like?

Comment: There it is: http://pastebin.com/0AXYJGMc

Comment: Hm, looks like all directories in your /tmp have the `setgid` flag on. Could you tell me how the output of `ls -l -d /tmp` looks like? Is `/tmp` on your system a separate partition? If so, what are its mount flags?

Comment: `tmp` is not on a separate partition. The output is `drwxrwsrwt 11 root root 4,0K oct.   9 12:04 /tmp/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I see that you are on version 4.0.14. Please upgrade to the latest version, which is 4.0.20. Versions prior to 4.0.17 or so didn't properly support /tmp directories with the setgid flag.

Comment: I updated, and waited till the log rotation, which occurred this morning, and passenger crashed all the same.

Comment: Strange, I tested your setup on 4.0.20 with a setgid /tmp and it worked for me. Can you try setting PassengerTempDir to a place that is not /tmp? That'll avoid any remaining problems that /tmp may impose.

Comment: Ok, looks like it's working this time (I removed the `setgid` flag). Thanks.

Comment: @Hongli: I'm getting the same "Tried to reuse existing server" error in Passenger 4.0.35, is this a regression?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Can you try setting PassengerTempDir to somewhere else (somewhere not /tmp) and check whether that helps?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, restart apache solve this problem.

```
$ /etc/init.d/httpd stop
$ /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Specifically, `stop` then `start` worked whereas `restart` failed.